# Distribution to model Binomial distribution with parameter $p$ in trial $n$ dependent on result from trial $n-1$?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, bayesian, binomial-distribution

I'm wondering how one can model a Binomial distribution as described in question.

E.g., $p = 0.5$ for trial $n = 0$; $p(n+1) = p(n) + 0.01$ if for trial $n$ Bernoulli(p(n)) samples to 1, else $p(n+1) = p(n) - 0.01$

What distribution would allow me to capture the probability of $n$ successes in such a scenario?

**EDIT** (for clarity, re placement of question on hold): My proposed stochastic process could be described exactly as according to whuber's comment below. Thank you whuber for the clarification. Copied here:

> (whuber): I didn't vote to close, but I am curious what you mean by "model a Binomial distribution," by "samples to 1," and by "capturing" a probability of successes.  Would it be correct to interpret your question as describing a stochastic process $(p_t,X_t),$ $t=0,1,2,\ldots,$ with $p_{t+1}=p_t+0.01(2X_t-1)$ and $X_t\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p_t);$ and, for any integers $n$ and $m,$ asking for the chance that $\sum_{t=0}^m X_t=n$?

The closest question I (surprisingly, I think) have found is this below for a multinomial with changing probabilities in each trial, but that deals with knowing the single set of differing probabilities from the outset, not the p in each trial depending on the results of previous trials, as I am seeking. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164222/generalizing-poissons-binomial-distribution-to-the-multinomial-case

Comment: Not sure what makes this unclear; unless I have missed something, to me the proposed circumstances seem clear enough. Perhaps one of the close-voters could explain to the OP what else would be required to make this clear?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I am curious what you mean by "model a Binomial distribution," by "samples to 1," and by "capturing" a probability of successes.  Would it be correct to interpret your question as describing a stochastic process $(p_t,X_t),$ $t=0,1,2,\ldots,$ with $p_{t+1}=p_t+0.01(2X_t-1)$ and $X_t\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p_t);$ and, for any integers $n$ and $m,$ asking for the chance that $\sum_{t=0}^m X_t=n$?